# Show that $B=\{(a, b)\subset R \mid a<b\}$ is a basis

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let X=Real numbers and B be
 `B={(a, b)\subset of R \mid a<b\}` is basis for in R
How do I show that B is a basis?
Where B is the set of all open intervals

Show that this is a basis.
Do I just use he definition?
And do I have to show it is a basis on R, the standard topology?

i.e(a,b) is open in this question

Comment: A basis of *what*?

Comment: I think the real numbers

Comment: I interpret it as a basis of the topology.

Answer (score 2):

First, for every $x\in R$ there is $x\in[x,x+1) \subset B$.

Second, for $B_1,B_2 \subset B$, $B_1 \cap B_2$ is still of the form $[a,b)$ or it is empty, hence for every $x\in B_1 \cap B_2$, there is $x\in B_3 (=B_1 \cap B_2)\subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Thus $B$ is a basis of $R$.

Comment: Right at the end, for B3 is equal to, is the bracket misplaces? Or do you do you mean something else?

Comment: @Jason I mean $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$, and $x\in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$ for brevity.

Comment: And btw the question is with an open interval on (a,b) not a half open one. Thanks for answering anyway. Does anything change in that sense , does it then become (x-1/2, x+1/2)? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Jason For first condition your choice $(x-1/2,x+1/2)$ is fine. For second condition the reasoning is analogous.

Comment: In what why does it differ? Would it still be correct?

Comment: @Jason For first condition, replace $[x,x+1)$ with $(x-1/2,x+1/2)$. For second condition, replace $[a,b)$ with $(a,b)$ then this argument still works. Well, actually I don't get what confuses you..

Answer (score 1):

The question is posed in a kind of a weird way, and also the text of the question does not match the title, so I'll assume that OP wants to prove that $B = \{(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}| a<b \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

To do this notice that every set $(a,b)$ such that $a<b$ is an open metric ball with radius $\epsilon = \frac{a+b}{2}$. So now we want to show that open metric balls form a basis of $\mathbb{R}$. To do this first note that $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of all open metric balls, and $\emptyset$ is union of no metric balls.

Now to show that if $U$ and $V$ are unions of open metric balls, then so is $U \cap V$. Take $x \in U \cap V$, then $x$ is in the intersection of two open balls $B_1 =B_{\epsilon_1}(x_1)$ and $B_2 =B_{\epsilon_2}(x_2)$, so now define $a := min(\epsilon_1 - d(x,x_1), \epsilon_2 - d(x,x_2))$. Now, if $y \in B_a(x)$ then $d(y,x_1) \le d(y,x) + d(x,x_1) \le a$ so $y \in B_1$ and by similar argument $y \in B_2$. So $y \in  B_1 \cap B_2$ and $B_a(x) \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Now as this is true for every $x$ we get that the intersection is a union of open balls.

Finally we should show that a union of unions of open metric balls is a union of open metric balls but that is true by definition.